# Recoding categorical variables into binary variables in the same way on multiple data sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recode

I built a model using binary variables to represent categorical variables. I am trying to us the same binning and recodes I used in my research environment on production data. I use pyodc to query and pull realtime data that has the same elements as my development data did have, before I recoded it into binary variables. I want to keep the same designations from my development data in order to be able to reuse all my old code. When I developed this I used label encoder to change the strings to numbers, then code similar to below to make binary variables. this is proving to be difficult on production data as the number of categories is highly variable. how do I keep it consistent?

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.NAME_VKORG)
df["NAME_VKORG_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_VKORG)
le.fit(df.NAME_VTWEG)
df["NAME_VTWEG_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_VTWEG)
le.fit(df.NAME_LGMNG)
df["NAME_LGMNG_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_LGMNG)
le.fit(df.NAME_POSNR)
df["NAME_POSNR_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_POSNR)
le.fit(df.NAME_WERKS)
df["NAME_WERKS_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_WERKS)
le.fit(df.NAME_LGORT)
df["NAME_LGORT_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_LGORT)
le.fit(df.NAME_CODE)
df["NAME_CODE_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_CODE)
le.fit(df.NAME_VSTEL)
df["NAME_VSTEL_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_VSTEL)
le.fit(df.NAME_LPRIO)
df["NAME_LPRIO_Auto"] = le.transform(df.NAME_LPRIO)

df.loc[:,"NAME_LGMNG_1"] = np.where(df["NAME_LGMNG_Auto"] == 1,1,0)
df.loc[:,"NAME_LGMNG_2"] = np.where(df["NAME_LGMNG_Auto"] == 2,1,0)
df.loc[:,"NAME_LGMNG_3"] = np.where(df["NAME_LGMNG_Auto"] == 3,1,0)
df.loc[:,"NAME_LGMNG_4"] = np.where(df["NAME_LGMNG_Auto"] == 4,1,0)

#Should be noted there are many more of the above, just used some for 
examples
```

Comment: get_dummies ..........................

Comment: or use `np.select`

Comment: I'm not sure get_dummies is really the right solution. It will recode differently each time right? also sometimes I have 100s of categories but I only want to create binary variables for the top 25 this is what i want to keep consistent.